# Linux DMA: Using the DMAengine for scatter-gather transactions

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I try to use the DMAengine API from a custom kernel driver to perform a *scatter-gather* operation. I have a contiguous memory region as source and I want to copy its data in several distributed buffers through a **scatterlist** structure. The DMA controller is the PL330 one that supports the DMAengine API (see [PL330 DMA controller](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/dma/pl330.c)).

My test code is the following:

In my driver header file (`test_driver.h`):

```
#ifndef __TEST_DRIVER_H__
#define __TEST_DRIVER_H__

#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/device.h>

#include <linux/scatterlist.h>
#include <linux/dma-mapping.h>
#include <linux/dmaengine.h>
#include <linux/of_dma.h>

#define SG_ENTRIES 3
#define BUF_SIZE 16
#define DEV_BUF 0x10000000

struct dma_block {
    void * data;
    int size;
};

struct dma_private_info {

    struct sg_table sgt;

    struct dma_block * blocks;
    int nblocks;

    int dma_started;

    struct dma_chan * dma_chan;
    struct dma_slave_config dma_config;
    struct dma_async_tx_descriptor * dma_desc;
    dma_cookie_t cookie;
};

struct test_platform_device {
    struct platform_device * pdev;

    struct dma_private_info dma_priv;
};

#define _get_devp(tdev) (&((tdev)->pdev->dev))
#define _get_dmapip(tdev) (&((tdev)->dma_priv))

int dma_stop(struct test_platform_device * tdev);
int dma_start(struct test_platform_device * tdev);
int dma_start_block(struct test_platform_device * tdev);
int dma_init(struct test_platform_device * tdev);
int dma_exit(struct test_platform_device * tdev);

#endif
```

In my source that contains the dma functions (`dma_functions.c`):

```
#include <linux/slab.h>

#include "test_driver.h"

#define BARE_RAM_BASE 0x10000000
#define BARE_RAM_SIZE 0x10000000

struct ram_bare {
    uint32_t * __iomem map;

    uint32_t base;
    uint32_t size;
};

static void dma_sg_check(struct test_platform_device * tdev)
{
    struct dma_private_info * dma_priv = _get_dmapip(tdev);
    struct device * dev = _get_devp(tdev);
    uint32_t * buf;
    unsigned int bufsize;
    int nwords;
    int nbytes_word = sizeof(uint32_t);
    int nblocks;
    struct ram_bare ramb;
    uint32_t * p;
    int i;
    int j;

    ramb.map = ioremap(BARE_RAM_BASE,BARE_RAM_SIZE);
    ramb.base = BARE_RAM_BASE;
    ramb.size = BARE_RAM_SIZE;

    dev_info(dev,"nblocks: %d \n",dma_priv->nblocks);

    p = ramb.map;

    nblocks = dma_priv->nblocks;

    for( i = 0 ; i < nblocks ; i++ ) {

        buf = (uint32_t *) dma_priv->blocks[i].data;
        bufsize = dma_priv->blocks[i].size;
        nwords = dma_priv->blocks[i].size/nbytes_word;

        dev_info(dev,"block[%d],size %d: ",i,bufsize);

        for ( j = 0 ; j <  nwords; j++, p++) {
            dev_info(dev,"DMA: 0x%x, RAM: 0x%x",buf[j],ioread32(p));
        }
    }

    iounmap(ramb.map);
}

static int dma_sg_exit(struct test_platform_device * tdev)
{
    struct dma_private_info * dma_priv = _get_dmapip(tdev);
    int ret = 0;
    int i;

    for( i = 0 ; i < dma_priv->nblocks ; i++ ) {
        kfree(dma_priv->blocks[i].data);
    }

    kfree(dma_priv->blocks);

    sg_free_table(&(dma_priv->sgt));

    return ret;
}

int dma_stop(struct test_platform_device * tdev)
{
    struct dma_private_info * dma_priv = _get_dmapip(tdev);
    struct device * dev = _get_devp(tdev);
    int ret = 0;

    dma_unmap_sg(dev,dma_priv->sgt.sgl,\
        dma_priv->sgt.nents, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

    dma_sg_exit(tdev);

    dma_priv->dma_started = 0;

    return ret;
}

static void dma_callback(void * param)
{
    enum dma_status dma_stat;
    struct test_platform_device * tdev = (struct test_platform_device *) param;
    struct dma_private_info * dma_priv = _get_dmapip(tdev);
    struct device * dev = _get_devp(tdev);

    dev_info(dev,"Checking the DMA state....\n");

    dma_stat = dma_async_is_tx_complete(dma_priv->dma_chan,\
        dma_priv->cookie, NULL, NULL);

    if(dma_stat == DMA_COMPLETE) {
        dev_info(dev,"DMA complete! \n");
        dma_sg_check(tdev);
        dma_stop(tdev);
    } else if (unlikely(dma_stat == DMA_ERROR)) {
        dev_info(dev,"DMA error! \n");
        dma_stop(tdev);
    }
}

static void dma_busy_loop(struct test_platform_device * tdev)
{
    struct dma_private_info * dma_priv = _get_dmapip(tdev);
    struct device * dev = _get_devp(tdev);

    enum dma_status status;
    int status_change = -1;

    do {
        status = dma_async_is_tx_complete(dma_priv->dma_chan, dma_priv->cookie, NULL, NULL);

        switch(status) {
        case DMA_COMPLETE:
            if(status_change != 0)
                dev_info(dev,"DMA status: COMPLETE\n");
            status_change = 0;
            break;
        case DMA_PAUSED:
            if (status_change != 1)
                dev_info(dev,"DMA status: PAUSED\n");
            status_change = 1;
            break;
        case DMA_IN_PROGRESS:
            if(status_change != 2)
                dev_info(dev,"DMA status: IN PROGRESS\n");
            status_change = 2;
            break;
        case DMA_ERROR:
            if (status_change != 3)
                dev_info(dev,"DMA status: ERROR\n");
            status_change = 3;
            break;
        default:
            dev_info(dev,"DMA status: UNKNOWN\n");
            status_change = -1;
            break;
        }
    } while(status != DMA_COMPLETE);

    dev_info(dev,"DMA transaction completed! \n");
}

static int dma_sg_init(struct test_platform_device * tdev)
{

    struct dma_private_info * dma_priv = _get_dmapip(tdev);
    struct scatterlist *sg;
    int ret = 0;
    int i;

    ret = sg_alloc_table(&(dma_priv->sgt), SG_ENTRIES, GFP_ATOMIC);
    if(ret)
        goto out_mem2;

    dma_priv->nblocks = SG_ENTRIES;
    dma_priv->blocks = (struct dma_block *) kmalloc(dma_priv->nblocks\
        *sizeof(struct dma_block), GFP_ATOMIC);
    if(dma_priv->blocks == NULL) 
         goto out_mem1;


    for( i = 0 ; i < dma_priv->nblocks ; i++ ) {
        dma_priv->blocks[i].size = BUF_SIZE;
        dma_priv->blocks[i].data = kmalloc(dma_priv->blocks[i].size, GFP_ATOMIC);
        if(dma_priv->blocks[i].data == NULL)
            goto out_mem3;
    }

    for_each_sg(dma_priv->sgt.sgl, sg, dma_priv->sgt.nents, i)
        sg_set_buf(sg,dma_priv->blocks[i].data,dma_priv->blocks[i].size);

    return ret;

out_mem3:
    i--;

    while(i >= 0)
        kfree(dma_priv->blocks[i].data);

    kfree(dma_priv->blocks);

out_mem2:
    sg_free_table(&(dma_priv->sgt));

out_mem1:
    ret = -ENOMEM;  

    return ret;

}

static int _dma_start(struct test_platform_device * tdev,int block)
{
    struct dma_private_info * dma_priv = _get_dmapip(tdev);
    struct device * dev = _get_devp(tdev);
    int ret = 0;
    int sglen;

    /* Step 1: Allocate and initialize the SG list */
    dma_sg_init(tdev);

    /* Step 2: Map the SG list */
    sglen = dma_map_sg(dev,dma_priv->sgt.sgl,\
        dma_priv->sgt.nents, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
    if(! sglen)
        goto out2;

    /* Step 3: Configure the DMA */
    (dma_priv->dma_config).direction = DMA_DEV_TO_MEM;
    (dma_priv->dma_config).src_addr_width = DMA_SLAVE_BUSWIDTH_4_BYTES;
    (dma_priv->dma_config).src_maxburst = 1;
    (dma_priv->dma_config).src_addr = (dma_addr_t) DEV_BUF;

    dmaengine_slave_config(dma_priv->dma_chan, \
        &(dma_priv->dma_config));

    /* Step 4: Prepare the SG descriptor */
    dma_priv->dma_desc = dmaengine_prep_slave_sg(dma_priv->dma_chan, \
        dma_priv->sgt.sgl, dma_priv->sgt.nents, DMA_DEV_TO_MEM, \
        DMA_PREP_INTERRUPT | DMA_CTRL_ACK);
    if (dma_priv->dma_desc == NULL) {
        dev_err(dev,"DMA could not assign a descriptor! \n");
        goto out1;
    }

    /* Step 5: Set the callback method */
    (dma_priv->dma_desc)->callback = dma_callback;
    (dma_priv->dma_desc)->callback_param = (void *) tdev;

    /* Step 6: Put the DMA descriptor in the queue */
    dma_priv->cookie = dmaengine_submit(dma_priv->dma_desc);

    /* Step 7: Fires the DMA transaction */
    dma_async_issue_pending(dma_priv->dma_chan);

    dma_priv->dma_started = 1;

    if(block)
        dma_busy_loop(tdev);

    return ret;

out1:
    dma_stop(tdev);
out2:
    ret = -1;

    return ret;
}

int dma_start(struct test_platform_device * tdev) {
    return _dma_start(tdev,0);
}

int dma_start_block(struct test_platform_device * tdev) {
    return _dma_start(tdev,1);
}

int dma_init(struct test_platform_device * tdev)
{
    int ret = 0;
    struct dma_private_info * dma_priv = _get_dmapip(tdev);
    struct device * dev = _get_devp(tdev);

    dma_priv->dma_chan = dma_request_slave_channel(dev, \
        "dma_chan0");
    if (dma_priv->dma_chan == NULL) {
        dev_err(dev,"DMA channel busy! \n");
        ret = -1;
    }

    dma_priv->dma_started = 0;

    return ret;
}

int dma_exit(struct test_platform_device * tdev)
{
    int ret = 0;
    struct dma_private_info * dma_priv = _get_dmapip(tdev);

    if(dma_priv->dma_started) {
        dmaengine_terminate_all(dma_priv->dma_chan);
        dma_stop(tdev);
        dma_priv->dma_started = 0;
    }

    if(dma_priv->dma_chan != NULL)
        dma_release_channel(dma_priv->dma_chan);

    return ret;
}
```

In my driver source file (`test_driver.c`):

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/of_device.h>
#include <linux/of_address.h>
#include <linux/of_irq.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

#include "test_driver.h"

static int dma_block=0;
module_param_named(dma_block, dma_block, int, 0444);

static struct test_platform_device tdev;

static struct of_device_id test_of_match[] = {
  { .compatible = "custom,test-driver-1.0", },
  {}
};

static int test_probe(struct platform_device *op)
{
    int ret = 0;
    struct device * dev = &(op->dev);

    const struct of_device_id *match = of_match_device(test_of_match, &op->dev);

    if (!match)
        return -EINVAL;

    tdev.pdev = op;

    dma_init(&tdev);

    if(dma_block)
        ret = dma_start_block(&tdev);
    else
        ret = dma_start(&tdev);

    if(ret) {
        dev_err(dev,"Error to start DMA transaction! \n");
    } else {
        dev_info(dev,"DMA OK! \n");
    }

    return ret;
}

static int test_remove(struct platform_device *op)
{       
    dma_exit(&tdev);

    return 0;
}

static struct platform_driver test_platform_driver = {
  .probe = test_probe,
  .remove = test_remove,
  .driver = {
    .name = "test-driver",
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .of_match_table = test_of_match,
  },
};

static int test_init(void)
{
    platform_driver_register(&test_platform_driver);
    return 0;
}

static void test_exit(void)
{
    platform_driver_unregister(&test_platform_driver);
}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("klyone");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("DMA SG test module");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

However, the DMA never calls my callback function and I do not have any idea why it happens. Maybe, I am misunderstanding something...

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DMA is not part of the C standard, nor is it a common library like POSIX, etc. What are you talking about?

Comment: And C does not support _methods_.

Comment: The DMAengine is the API inside the Linux kernel to use DMA drivers. Sorry for the confusion, I think I can improve my question description...

Comment: Show your actual code. The line `dma_priv.dma_desc.callback = dma_callback;` obviously won't compile given that `dma_priv.dma_desc` is a pointer. You should also show the code that calls `dma_init` and `dma_start`.

Comment: @RossRidge Yes, it was a typo. The **dma_init** is called by my module init function and the **dma_start** is executed in a workqueue after a interrupt handler. I did not show that code because the problem is related with the DMAengine configuration...

Comment: You can't make any typos if you cut and paste your actual code. There's no point in anyone trying to debug code that you're not actually using.

Comment: I have simplified the code in order to focus the part that is failing now. For this reason, I have this typo. The whole code is very complicated and does not give additional information to solve the issue on the contrary it would be more confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Caveat:* I don't have a definitive solution for you, but merely some observations and suggestions on how to debug this [based on many years of experience writing/debugging linux device drivers].

I presume you believe the callback is *not* being done because you don't get any printk messages. But, the callback is the *only* place that has them. But, is the printk level set high enough to see the messages? I'd add a `dev_info` to your module init, to prove it prints as expected.

Also, you [probably] won't get a callback if `dma_start` doesn't work as expected, so I'd add some `dev_info` calls there, too (e.g. before and after the call in step 7). I also notice that not all calls in `dma_start` check error returns [may be fine or void return, just mentioning in case you missed one]

At this point, it should be noted that there are really *two* questions here: (1) Did your DMA request start successfully [and *complete*]? (2) Did you get a callback?

So, I'd split off some code from `dma_complete` into (e.g.) `dma_test_done`. The latter does the same checking but only prints the "complete" message. You can call this in a poll mode to verify DMA completion.

So, if you [eventually] get a completion, then the problem reduces to why you didn't get the callback. If, however, you don't [even] get a completion, that's an even more fundamental problem.

This reminds me. You didn't show any code that calls `dma_start` or how you *wait* for the completion. I presume that if your callback were working, it would issue a wakeup of some sort that the base level would wait on. Or, the callback would do the request deallocate/cleanup (i.e. more code you'd write)

At step 7, you're calling `dma_async_issue_pending`, which should call `pl330_issue_pending`. `pl330_issue_pending` will call `pl330_tasklet`.

`pl330_tasklet` is a *tasklet* function, but it can also be called directly [to kick off DMA when there are no active requests].

`pl330_tasklet` will loop on its "work" queue and move any completed items to its "completed" queue. It then tries to start new requests. It then loops on its completed queue and issues the callbacks.

`pl330_tasklet` grabs the callback pointer, but if it's null it is silently ignored. You've set a callback, but it might be good to verify that where *you* set the callback is the same place [or propagates to] the place where `pl330_tasklet` will fetch it from.

When you make the call, everything may be busy, so there are *no* completed requests, *no* room to start a new request, so *nothing* to complete. In that case, `pl330_tasklet` will be called again later.

So, when `dma_async_issue_pending` returns, *nothing* may have happened *yet*. This is quite probable for your case.

`pl330_tasklet` tries to start new DMA by calling `fill_queue`. It will check that a descriptor is not [already] busy by looking at `status != BUSY`. So, you may wish to verify that yours has the correct value. Otherwise, you'd *never* get a callback [or even any DMA start].

Then, `fill_queue` will try to start the request via `pl330_submit_req`. But, that can return an error (e.g. queue already full), so, again, things are deferred.

For reference, notice the following comment at the top of `pl330_submit_req`:

```
Submit a list of xfers after which the client wants notification.
Client is not notified after each xfer unit, just once after all
xfer units are done or some error occurs.
```

What I'd do is start hacking up `pl330.c` and add debug messages and cross-checking. If your system is such that pl330 is servicing *many* other requests, you might limit the debug messages by checking that the device's private data pointer matches yours.

In particular, you'd like to get a message when your request actually gets started, so you could add a debug message to the end of `pl330_submit_req`

Then, adding messages within `pl330_tasklet` for requests will help, too.

Those are two good starting points. But, don't be afraid to add more printk calls as needed. You may be surprised by what gets called [or *doesn't* get called] or in what order.

---

**UPDATE:**

> If I install the kernel module with the blocking behaviour, everything is initialized well. However, the dma_busy_loop function shows that the DMA descriptor is always IN PROGESS and the DMA transaction never completes. For this reason, the callback function is not executed. What could be happening?

Did a little more research. Cookies are just sequence numbers that increment. For example, if you issue a request that gets broken up into [say] 10 separate scatter/gather operations [descriptors], each one gets a unique cookie value. The cookie return value is the latest/last of the bunch (e.g. 10).

When you're calling (1) `dma_async_is_tx_complete`, (2) it calls `chan->device->device_tx_status`, (3) which is `pl330_tx_status`, (4) which calls `dma_cookie_status`

*Side note/tip:* When I was tracking this down, I just kept flipping back and forth between `dmaengine.h` and `pl330.c`. It was like: Look at (1), it calls (2). Where is that set? In `pl330.c`, I presume. So, I grepped for the string and got the name of pl330's function (i.e. (3)). So, I go there, and see that it does (4). So ... Back to `dmaengine.h` ...

However, when you make the outer call, you're ignoring [setting to NULL] the last two arguments. These can be useful because they return the "last" and "used" cookies. So, even if you don't get full completion, these values could change and show partial progress.

One of them should eventually be >= to the "return" cookie value. (i.e.) The entire operation should be complete. So, this will help differentiate what may be happening.

Also, note that in `dmaengine.h`, right below `dma_async_is_tx_complete`, there is `dma_async_is_complete`. This function is what decides whether to return `DMA_COMPLETE` or `DMA_IN_PROGRESS`, based on the cookie value you pass and the "last" and "used" cookie values. It's passive, and not used in the code path [AFAICT], but it does show how to calculate completion yourself.

Comment: First of all, thanks for sharing your experience with me. I have improved my code to find where is the problem. Now, my driver accepts a dma_block parameter that allows to configure a blocking or non-blocking behaviour (wait or not the DMA transaction). If I install the kernel module with the blocking behaviour, everything is initialized well. However, the `dma_busy_loop` function shows that the DMA descriptor is always `IN PROGESS` and the DMA transaction never completes. For this reason, the callback function is not executed. What could be happening? Thanks.

Comment: I want to apologize for taking so long to get back to you on this. I've added an update to my answer with some more specific information. Don't know what state you're in, or what progress you've been able to make, so, hopefully, you're up and running. Either way, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Sorry for the big delay to answer you. My problem is more basic than everything we discussed above. I try to perform a sg operation between two RAM memory regions and I have checked that it does not like to the PL330 driver. It suposes that the device address always uses a FIFO. For this reason, the DMA does not show any progress and the callback function is not executed. 

The conclusion is I have to add a new feature to the driver in order to be able to run a sg operation in these circustances. Thanks a lot for your support!